# Continuity of the middle root for monic real polynomials of degree three

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

For $a=(a_0,a_1,a_2)\in {\mathbb R}^3$, let $P_a=X^3+a_2X^2+a_1X+a_0$. It is well-known that $P_a$ has either three (not necessarily distinct) real roots $r_1 \leq r_2 \leq r_3$ or a single real root, which we still denote by $r_2$.

Clearly, $r_2$ is continuous at the points $a$ where the discriminant of $P_a$ is nonzero (in fact $r_2$ is ${\mathcal C}^{\infty}$ around those points).

Unexpectedly, $r_2$ is also continuous at $(0,0,0)$. To see why, consider $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+x+1}$. Since $f'(x)=\frac{x^2\big((x+1)^2+2\big)}{(x^2+x+1)^2} \gt 0$, we see that $f$ is a ${\mathcal C}^{\infty}$-diffeomorphism ${\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$.

Now, let $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and let $a=(a_0,a_1,a_2)\in {\mathbb R}^3$ with $|a_k| \leq \varepsilon$. For $x\gt 0$, we have
$$P_a(x)=x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 \geq x^3-\varepsilon(x^2+x+1)=(x^2+x+1)(f(x)-\varepsilon)$$ and this is $\gt 0$ for $x\gt f^{-1}(\varepsilon)$. A similar argument shows that $P_a(x)\lt 0$ for $x \lt -f^{-1}(\varepsilon)$.  Thus all the roots of $P_a$ must lie in $[-f^{-1}(\varepsilon),f^{-1}(\varepsilon)]$ and hence $|r_2(a)| \leq f^{-1}(\varepsilon)$. This shows $\lim_{a\to 0}r_2(a)=0$ as wished.

On the other hand,  $r_2$ is not continous at $(0,1,-2)$ : we have $r_2(X(X-1)^2)=1$ but $r_2(X((X-1)^2+t))=0$ for every $t\gt 0$.

Hence my

**Question :** What are the points of continuity of $r_2$ ?

A similar question may be asked for any odd degree, for an odd-degree real polynomial has an odd number of (not necessarily distinct) real roots.

Comment: You know about the relation between the coefficient of a polynomial and it's roots, through the elementary symmetric polynomials - in other words, the sum of the roots equals what you call $a_2$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: @Thomas How do symmetric polynomials help here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P_a$ has three distinct zeros then (as you say) all three zeros of $P_b$ are continuous functions of $b$ in a neighborhood of $a$.

If $P_a$ has a triple zero then also all three zeros of $P_b$ are continuous functions of $b$ at $a$: Without loss of generality we can assume that $a=0$, and it is not difficult to show that for $b = (b_0, b_1, b_2)$ with $\max|b_j| < \epsilon$, all three zeros of $P_b$ satisfy $|x_k| < (3 \epsilon)^{1/3}$.

However, if $P_a$ has a simple and a double zero then it is of the form
$$
 P_a(x) = (x-c)(x-d)^2
$$
with distinct real numbers $c, d$. We have $r_2(P_a) = d$, but
$$
 r_2\big((x-c)((x-d)^2 + t)\bigr) = c
$$
for any $t > 0$, so that $r_2$ is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: Thanks for this satisfying answer. How do you show that all three zeros of $P_b$ satisfy $|x_k| < (3 \epsilon)^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Write $|x|^3 = |b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0| \le \epsilon (|x|^2+|x| +1)$ and consider the cases $|x| \le 1$ and $|x| > 1$. – I'll see if I can find a reference to another nice bound.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: You can find various bounds here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots, giving an upper bound for the modulus of all zeros in terms of the moduli of the coefficients.